# Converting Range with a Function Similar to Log(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

I want to convert a number from range `[x1, x2]` to `[y1, y2]`. Except that I want the first few numbers to have more effect. Similar to the log(x) function.

For example if I want to convert `[0, 100]` to `[0, 1]`, I want to have results similar to these:

```
0    ->   0
10   ->   0.5
50   ->   0.7
90   ->   0.96
99   ->   0.999
100  ->   1
```

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a function of the form $f(x) = k \cdot x^\alpha$

where

$0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$

Just pick whatever $k$ and $\alpha$ constants suit you best.

The requirement that $f(0) = 0$ is satisfied.

So try for example $\alpha=1/2$, $\alpha=2/3$, $\alpha=3/4$, etc.
and then pick the appropriate values for $k$ to satisfy $f(100)=1$.

Plot these functions and you will see what happens.

Comment: Yes; for $f(x) = y$, the appropriate value for $k$ being $k = y / x^\alpha$.